# Min-max stretch using gdal_translate in a batch

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate, histogram

I'm trying to do a min-max stretch on a raster and save it using [gdal_translate](https://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html). The syntax requires to enter source min and max raster values as arguments for a `-scale` option:

`-scale [src_min src_max [dst_min dst_max]]`

My goal is to **populate those src_min and src_max automatically** to do conversions in a batch.

The docs even state that they are computed if ommited:

```
Rescale the input pixels values from the range src_min to src_max to the range dst_min to dst_max. If omitted the input range is automatically computed from the source data.
```

But in reality `gdal_translate -scale 0 65535 src_16b.tif dst_16b.tif` does not produce correct results. What may be wrong?

Comment: What result does it produce and what result would you like to get? The whole sentense in the documentation seems to be `Rescale the input pixels values from the range src_min to src_max to the range dst_min to dst_max. If omitted the output range is 0 to 255. If omitted the input range is automatically computed from the source data.` Thus your command should do the same than `-scale 0 65535 0 255`. Plain `-scale` should then convert from auto-min auto-max into range 0-255.

Comment: I have 10 bits of useful data and I'd like to stretch it along 16 bit. This is why I'm not satisfied with a plain -scale - it defaults output range to 8 bit so I'll loose information if I do it.

Comment: Gdal_translate does not support directly what you are after. You'll need some Python for reading min and max from the source and passing them to -scale.

Answer (score 2):

You could solve it using a Bash script and Awk:

```
minmax=$(gdalinfo -mm file.tif|awk -F= '/Computed Min/ {print $2}')
min=$(echo $minmax|awk -F, '{print $1}')
max=$(echo $minmax|awk -F, '{print $2}')
gdal_translate -scale $min $max 0 65535 file.tif out.tif
```

Comment: The output of the 'gdalinfo -mm' command has changed. If failing with a max value of 'Max', the first line should be changed to:
`minmax=$(gdalinfo -mm file.tif|awk -FMin/Max= '/Computed Min/ {print $2}')`